# Do the elements for bystander IIED include defendant knowing the bystander both was present and related to the victim?

Tags: tort

I am studying for the bar exam (United States). I have encountered two different versions of the elements for bystander Intentional Infliction of Emotional Distress (IIED). I am not sure which is correct. I have bolded the inconsistency. I am pretty sure the first bolded part in VERSION 1 is incorrect. But the second bolded part I am not too sure about. Tell me which version is correct, along with an explanation. If neither is correct provide the correct answer.

VERSION 1:

A bystander victim can recover under IIED if (1) the bystander is a close relative of the victim or **suffers some physical harm**, (2) the bystander is physically present when the actor commits the tort against the victim, and (3) **the defendant knew the bystander both was present and related to the victim.**

VERSION 2:

BYSTANDER CLAIM: Arises if a bystander suffers severe emotional distress from seeing that actor’s negligence has injured a third party, the primary victim. Most jdxs let bystander recover for this stand-alone emotional distress if elements are met: (1) there must be a close family relationship between the bystander and the primary victim; (2) presence and contemporaneous observation; (3) bystander must observe, or perceive, the injury as it occurs. Some jurisdictions have a fourth element, which is that the primary victim must suffer severe bodily injury or death.

Comment: IANAL, so this is just my observations and guesses, but the first version seems to be a for a specific jurisdiction and the second version seems to be more general. Also the first version mentions IIED, where the first I is for _intentional_, so the second bolded part seems crucial. If absent, I could imagine a lesser offense might be relevant.

Comment: The cases you are discussing are negligent infliction of emotional distress (NIED) fact patterns, not IIED cases a.k.a. "outrageous conduct" cases.